# Fuzzy set operation AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence, operators, fuzzy-logic

If fuzzy set A={(10,0.2),(20,0.4),(25,0.1),(5,0.8)} and fuzzy set B={(10,0.4),(20,0.3),(25,0.6)} what should be the answer for union and intersection?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You might want to ask that question on the AI stackexchange.